# Install Ubuntu on 2017 Macbook Pro 15', EFI boot doesn't work lead to grub

Tags: system-installation, usb, mac, macbook-pro

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my 2017 MacBook Pro with Touch Bar (15') with USB stick. I have created the USB drive and I have tested it for functionality on my old MacBook Pro (2014). However, it doesn't work on my new MBP, the situation is after I get into Startup Manager by pressing Option key when starting the machine, whichever 'EFI Boot' option won't lead the system to GRUB of Ubuntu installation, both of these two options start MacOS as the same result of choosing Macintosh.

Anyone can help me on that? Thanks.

[image: boot devices image with "Macintosh HD" "EFI boot" and "EFI boot"]